# Firebase delete child with security rule !data.exists on write

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a security rule for adding new data

```
 "CATEGORIES": {
      "$CATEGORIES": {
      ".write":   "root.child('USERS/' + auth.uid + '/type').val() == 'admin' && !data.exists() || root.child('USERS/' + auth.uid + '/type').val() == 'admin' && root.child('MODES/delete').val() == 'yes'",
       "$DATA": {
         ".write":   "root.child('USERS/' + auth.uid + '/type').val() == 'admin'",
       }
      }
      }
```

It's used to prevent duplicates or overwriting of the child node with the `!data.exists()` rule.

Problems is, it wont let me delete the child with this rule because data exists. To get around this I added the `root.child('MODES/delete').val()` data to allow me to delete it if I set it to 'yes'.

How can I have it so I don't have to do this work around? So I can have no duplicates but also be able to delete the child if I want to?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To allow creates but no overwriting, `!data.exists()` works fine. To allow deletes, you can use `!newData.exists()`.

So all together:

```
// create or delete, but no update/overwrite
".write":  "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"
```