# In firebase, can I set permissions to allow only PUSH operations to a given object?

Tags: firebase

The title says it all.  I want to grant permissions to push new objects to a given list-style database, but I don't want to allow full write permissions.  In this possible?

Comment: For a variant of this question, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779134/firebase-delete-child-with-security-rule-data-exists-on-write/20787137#20787137

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not sure what "not allow full write permissions" means or that the title does indeed say it all. But let's assume this means you want to be able to add records but not delete or modify them? Making these assumptions, you could simply do a write rule as follows:

```
// !data.exists(): only push once, no edits
// newData.exists(): cannot delete
".write": "!data.exists()"
```

Comment: Glad to help! A few of the recipes under firebase.com/docs include examples of security rules that might also give you some good ideas.

Comment: Isn't the newData.exists() check unnecessary? If !data.exists() then surely you'd be trying to delete something that isn't there?!

Comment: It does seem superfluous. Why are you shouting?!

Comment: Does `".write": "newData.exists()"` mean it is possible to add (allowing duplicates)  but not delete? If so what about same without duplicates?