# Firebase: prevent all but .push to a list

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, angularfire2

I have read [In firebase, can I set permissions to allow only PUSH operations to a given object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017256/in-firebase-can-i-set-permissions-to-allow-only-push-operations-to-a-given-obje) and so far copied it, but it does not work.

I have a site that is used anonymously, and where I collect comments. I want to store new ones to be added, but to prevent editing and deleting of existing data.

**Angular 2, with AngularFire2**

```
export class FirebaseService {

  comments: FirebaseListObservable<Object>;
  locations: FirebaseListObservable<Object>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
      this.comments = this.af.database.list(environment.stem + '/comments');    
  }

  addComment(comment) {
    return this.comments.push(comment)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
}
```

I expected this rule would do it as there will be no existing data in the case that I push?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "!data.exists()"
  }
}
```

Setting the write rule to `true` makes it work but looser than I want.

Here are the beginnings of the existing json in this route of the database (the keys here come from a service I am migrating away from)

```
{
  "0763a8d3e2407697" : {
    "comment" : "Thanks for your comments and feedback, Simon",
    "date" : "Sat Jan 03 2015 08:46:17 GMT+0100 (CET)"
  },...
```

Comment: Can you add the code for an operation that you want to allow *and* the code for an operation that you want to reject? Also please add the existing JSON at the location (as text, no screenshots please).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen See updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current rules, the database server will reject the write whenever *any* data exists in the database.

But your use-case seems to only want to reject write that overwrite a specific existing comment. For that use-case, you should put the `.write` rule lower into the tree:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "$stemid": {
      "comments": {
        "$commentid": {
          ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These rules [use `$ variables`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments) to ensure they apply across all stems and all comments.